# Cant perform view click in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Fragment Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/CardViewStyle1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/scale_40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivClose"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/scale_25dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/scale_25dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/close_red" />
            </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**In Fragment**

```
    ImageView ivClose;
    ivClose = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivClose);
    ivClose .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              Log.e("onClick","onClick");  // Cant detect 
            }
        });
```

I am facing this strange issue regarding button click in a fragment, tried few solutions didn't work, Am I missing something?..any help would be appreciated !!!

Please read below scenario before answering:

> There are two fragments I am moving from 1->2 , 2->1 and when I try to
>   access view (in my case ivClose imageview) click from fragment(1), it
>   again goes to 2 it supposed to close fragment(1) and return to
>   activity, it's working well with default back button key of device.

Comment: show full activity

Comment: @phpdroid its long what do you want to know?

Comment: where you loading fragment?

Comment: Why don't you try onClick Listener on Button's object in fragment then use `getActivity().onBackPressed()`

Comment: onClick() method defined in xml don't work with fragments. You have to set click listener via code.

Comment: @phpdroid Check edits

Comment: @Sharp Edge I have tried

Comment: @Vivek Mishra I have tried

Comment: `android:onClick` not work from FRAGMENT

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya I have tried with setOnClickListener in fragment but its not working dont know why

Comment: if you have done that then post that code as current one is of no use.

Comment: @VivekMishra Check edited que

Comment: remove clickable attribute from your cardview in xml

Comment: @VivekMishra let me try, btw i have put that cause it hit the activity views from fragment

Comment: @VivekMishra It didn't work, there are two fragments i am moving from 1->2 , 2->1 and when i try to access view click from (1) fragment it again goes to 2 it supposed to close (1)fragment and return to activity , its working well with default back button key of device

Comment: I just tested with the code that you have provided and it is working fine for me. You may be missing something else.

Comment: @VivekMishra okay, this is weird never had this kind of issue !!, Is this because bindview i had used and removed it later in fragment, any idea?

Comment: how have called your fragment class ? Via transactions or in the xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154530/discussion-between-nisarg-and-vivek-mishra).

Answer (score 1):

The onClick attribute will work fine as long as you define a method with the same name in your activity.

However, for Fragments the method needs to be defined in the calling activity.

It's probably easier to implement a click listener for the button in your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Use properly access to `View` like `findViewById(R.id.btn_close).setOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't use onClicked() method in Fragment.

you can only use in Activity class.

In Fragments, you have to get button instance from findViewById() method and then apply onClickListener to use it.